# Get Bundle Product to display its "base" simple product with Special and Regular Prices

Tags: discount, bundle, bundle-product, special-price

My site sells Bundled Products (Laptops/Desktops). The product is set up as follows: The bundle product's price is dynamic. A simple required product (the laptop itself) that has a price and inventory - this forms the base or minimum price of the bundle. Then the options are set up as optional simple products (they also have a price and inventory and must be set up in this way as we have limited inventory and different prices for bulk users). See link below:
http://www.refreshedbyus.com/lenovo-t420-laptop-b
This works well *except* for one big issue - I need to be able to put the base simple product of the bundle on sale and have the old/new prices be visible. I can put the simple product on sale and it will display the correct price, but not the strike-through old price.

I need to keep the set up as is for the reasons above - i.e. each of the products and options have set prices for groups and inventory. I can't apply the bundle percentage discount as it will discount the whole lot - I only want to discount the simple product.

Any ideas?! Please let me know. Have tried countless solutions and have looked through this forum and others and the answer to this question I cannot find.

Comment: only two years later, still looking for the answer! Anyone?!